# Possible method to prove infinite twin prime conjecture

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, prime-numbers

I have an idea looking more and more promising that may lead to proving the infinite twin prime conjecture. My idea would set up a correspondence between primes and twin prime pairs. Since primes have been proven infinite, twin primes would be shown infinite as well. Here it is:

For every prime $p>7$ there exists at least one unique twin prime pair $(p_t,p_t+2)$ created using only primes less than $p$ as follows:

$$(p_t,p_t+2)=(3\times5\times P_p\times p-4,\ \ 3\times 5\times p\times P_p-2)$$

or

$$(p_t,p_t+2)=(3\times5\times P_p\times p+2,\ \ 3\times5\times p\times P_p+4)$$

where $P_p$ is some product of individual primes ($p_n$) and their powers (*although recent developments indicate powers may be unnecessary!*) such that each fits the following condition:

$$5<p_n<p$$

Here's a few examples:

$(3\times5\times43-4,\ \ 3\times5\times43-2)=(641,643)$

$(3\times5\times7^2\times11\times47+2,\ \ 3\times5\times7^2\times11\times47+4)=(379997,379999)$

My request is for one of the following:

1. Someone to refine our program for a brute force testing method trying to find a counter-example to disprove my conjecture. Here's the code:

[Original Wolfram Notebook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/TwinPrimes.nb)

[NEW AND IMPROVED Wolfram Notebook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/TwinPrimes%20Opt.cdf)

2. **Someone to develop a proof of my conjecture; perhaps something related to the fact that the multitude of combinations/permutations etc. of primes ($5<p_p<p$) and their powers *requires* that there be at least one twin prime pair created. Perhaps a proof by contradiction? I.e. $p$ exists such that no twin prime is created is proven absurd, thus each $p$ maps to a unique twin prime, and as primes are infinite, so are twin primes? *Need some help here!* Maybe someone with rep to spare set a bounty?**

EDIT (2/15/16)
Thanks to @dbanet, I now have code needing some refinements. Still, what's astonishing is that we've checked the first $10,000$ primes and each has its own unique twin prime pair... and it didn't even require powers of primes; **everything is to the 1st power!** This fact alone should lend high credence to the conjecture that each prime may be mapped to (at least one) unique twin prime pair. I'm considering perhaps removing powers of primes from the original question.

Here's the list up to 109 for verification. You can check each by adding $4$ or subtracting $2$ from the first in the pair and looking at the prime factors. All will include $3$, $5$ , $p$, and primes between $5$ and $p$ all to the $1$st power (prime#, prime, twin prime):

`4, 7, {101},{103}
5, 11, {1151},{1153}
6, 13, {191},{193}
7, 17, {4337},{4339}
8, 19, {281},{283}
9, 23, {347},{349}
10, 29, {431},{433}
11, 31, {461},{463}
12, 37, {17207},{17209}
13, 41, {617},{619}
14, 43, {641},{643}
15, 47, {1225997},{1225999}
16, 53, {37361},{37363}
17, 59, {881},{883}
18, 61, {55817},{55819}
19, 67, {3616997},{3616999}
20, 71, {1061},{1063}
21, 73, {1091},{1093}
22, 79, {6141857},{6141859}
23, 83, {5922461},{5922463}
24, 89, {546625097},{546625099}
25, 97, {1451},{1453}
26, 101, {134837},{134839}
27, 103, {13888001},{13888003}
28, 107, {1607},{1609}
29, 109, {16969661},{16969663}`

EDIT (2/15/16)PM
Got a new list of twin primes because of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107417/memory-limit-hit-optimize-code-for-finding-twin-primes .

Here's the list of primes $2000-10000$ with the corresponding twin prime pairs!
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/8000%20twin%20primes.txt

And just for kicks here's the $100,000,000$th prime with the first found (probably not only) twin prime unique to it: $2038074743$ -- $(126984732620985857058143952617,$ $126984732620985857058143952619)$

Comment: Is there any restriction on $P_p$? From what is in the post $P_p$ can be as big as you want, so chances are you are going to hit a twin prime pair given that it is currently not proved there are not infinitely many of them and that we keep finding them.

Comment: @dbanet No restriction other than that mentioned (it can only include primes and their powers between 5 and $p$). Again, the goal is to show they're infinite. Most I've worked with though, require just one or two factors. For programming, an upper bound of 5 factors and 5th powers should **more** than suffice.

Comment: I liked the beginning of this proof. It is like the analogy of proving infinite primes through Fermat numbers. All Fermat numbers are relatively prime, which means they correspond with different prime numbers. Since there are an infinite number of Fermat numbers, there are an infinite number of primes. Was that your inspiration for this proof ?

Comment: "$P_p$ is some product of individual primes...and their powers" makes it sound like $P_p$ can be any number, since any number can be factored into primes.

Comment: @BenS. the primes that comprise it have to have $5 < p_p < p$ so it isn't just an arbitrary number.

Comment: @ChrisDugan Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I must have skipped that line.

Comment: @user230452 Thanks! My thought process was far more simplistic. $2*3*5*7-1$ etc. is not divisible by said numbers but gets large.

Comment: @user230452  $5*7-2*3$ also can't be divisible by said numbers and is smaller. Then my mind went to twin primes both $3*5*7-2$ and $3*5*7-4$ can't be divisible by anything less than 11 and are only 2 apart thus a ...pseudo-twin-prime?

Comment: @BenS Exactly. This keeps each twin prime unique from all previous as no previous twin prime was allowed to use the current $p$.

Comment: The title of this post is misleading: there is nothing in this question about a possible proof. It might conceivably be a _construction_ of infinitely many twin primes (not a very practical one though), but there not even a hint of a proof that this is true.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Sorry Marc, not very knowledgeable. My thought was that a construction of infinitely many unique twin primes each correlating to a consecutive prime would prove infinitely many twin primes exist. My title was meant to say that my thoughts might possibly be used to prove infinite twin primes. Do you (or anyone else) have an alternate suggestion for the title?

Comment: If infinitely many primes are constructed, doesn't it mean there are infinitely many of them ?

Comment: I don't think it's worth a bounty. I don't see any possible way this question would get us closer to proving the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: I don't upvote all questions I answer. However, I upvoted this one. I was specially looking for a question that I could write an answer like my answer to. I thought it might give some ideas leading to a proof of the twin prime conjecture. I specially searched the phrase "ideas for twin prime conjecture" in the Mathematics Stack Exchange search bar. Sometimes I see a question that doesn't appear useful at all so I don't upvote it but now that it was asked, I answer it because I can figure out how to answer it.

Comment: This question had a score of 8. I upvoted it. Now it has a score of 10. That means somebody else upvoted it so soon after I first began contributing to this question. I'm curious how that happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram Language code to test whether does $p$ provide the twin prime number pair via your conjecture or not is as follows.

```
twinPrimesQ[tp_]:=tp[[1]]+2==tp[[2]]&&PrimeQ[tp[[1]]]&&PrimeQ[tp[[2]]];
primesList[p_]:=Module[{out={Prime[3]},i},
    For[i=4,Prime[i]<=p,i=i+1,
        out=Append[out,Prime[i]];
    ];
    out
];
testPrime[p_,pl_]:=Module[{out,found=False,twinPrimes,primeFactors,primeFactorsPowers,i},
    twinPrimes={
        {3 5 prod p-4,3 5 prod p-2},
        {3 5 prod p+2,3 5 prod p+4}
    };
    primeFactors=primesList[p];
    primeFactorsPowers=Tuples[Range[0,pl],primeFactors//Length];
    For[i=1,i<=Length[primeFactorsPowers],i=i+1,
        out=twinPrimes/.prod->Product[primeFactors[[k]]^primeFactorsPowers[[i]][[k]],{k,1,primeFactors//Length}];
        found=twinPrimesQ[out[[1]]]||twinPrimesQ[out[[2]]];
        If[found,Break[]];
    ];
    If[found,out~Select~(twinPrimesQ[#]&)//First,False]
];
```

This defines a function `twinPrime[p,pl]` where `p`=$\,p$ and `pl` is the maximum power of prime factors of $P_p$ to search upon. The function returns the first found twin pair or `False` if it has failed.

For example:

[image: usage example]

You [can try this online](http://mathics.angusgriffith.com/#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) with [Mathics](http://mathics.org/).

To confirm or disprove your conjecture for ranges of primes, you can use

```
out=List[]; For[i=4,i<=7,i=i+1,out=out~Append~{i,Prime[i],testPrime[Prime[i],1]}]; out//TableForm
```

adjusting the bounds of search (values of `j` in terms of consecutive number of primes) and maximum power of prime factors. This will output a table with three columns: the id of the prime being tested, the prime itself and the first twin prime pair found (or `False` if none).

Comment: Wow this is cool! I don't think I'm using it right though. I'm getting the following: "
`out=List[]; For[j=4,j<=7,j=j+1,out=out~Append~{j,Prime[j],testPrime[Prime[j],1]}]; out//TableForm
45677111317If[twinPrimeQ[{7871,7873}]||twinPrimeQ[{7877,7879}],First[Select[out$125,twinPrimesQ[#1]&]],False]If[twinPrimeQ[{4121,4123}]||twinPrimeQ[{4127,4129}],First[Select[out$127,twinPrimesQ[#1]&]],False]If[twinPrimeQ[{5846,5848}]||twinPrimeQ[{5852,5854}],First[Select[out$129,twinPrimesQ[#1]&]],False]If[twinPrimeQ[{8921,8923}]||twinPrimeQ[{8927,8929}],First[Select[out$131,twinPrimesQ[#1]&]],False]` "

Comment: It gives me a load of code rather than the twin prime or false for the 3rd collumn. The first 2 show correctly...

Comment: Strange. It works for me if I just open the link. Make sure you evaluate (Shift-Enter) the first cell to have the functions defined before you actually use them in the second and the third cells. http://i.imgur.com/7jPdlHy.png

Comment: Hmm... Never used it before so must still be doing something wrong:

Comment: Here's what I get: http://imgur.com/n5tGk1J I'm right clicking your link, opening in new tab, clicking the last line of the first cell and hitting Shift-Enter, bar turns orangish, doing the same for second and third cells, then that's what I'm getting.

Comment: Wow. Strange shit. Issue confirmed, however, and your screenshot was helpful. I have updated the code and the link with the appropriate changes addressing the problem. Have fun! :)

Comment: Works great now! Here's $p<100$ only using first exponent: http://imgur.com/Hy10DJV

Comment: Found another glitch I think. In your `out=List[]` cell, try `j=16,j<=16` then try `j=15,j<=16`. I think it's looking at the first one, then only using those same factors for every one that follows.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. Can you please elaborate on the issue, including steps to reproduce, expected and actual results? I have, by the way, fixed a typo in the first Module definition that may be related.

Comment: Reloaded, and now I only get http://imgur.com/VEVfLym . Before, i was getting different numbers for j=16 depending on if I included j=15. Now I get "error".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35723/discussion-between-dbanet-and-user3363795).

Comment: Created a new question for this code here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656810/memory-limit-hit-optimize-code

Comment: And here's a link to the Mathematica Notebook: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/TwinPrimes.nb

Comment: Question changed location: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107417/memory-limit-hit-optimize-code-for-finding-twin-primes . Code is now a lot faster! Found it succeeds through first 10,000 primes!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see at all how the idea in this question would get us any closer to proving the twin prime conjecture. I know that sometimes, ideas that appear to get you no closer actually do get you closer. For example, Bertrand's postulate states that there is no prime number that is more than double the previous prime number. There's actually a proof of Bertrand's postulate that's not very long, and it's gotten by combining many results each of which appears to not be at all useful for proving Bertrand's postulate. The proof can be found in the Wikipedia article [Proof of Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate).

I have another idea. The notion of $Z_n$ has been invented by the mathematical community. In $Z_n$, the only numbers are the integers from 0 to $n - 1$. Addition in $Z_n$ is also defined as follows. To add two numbers in $Z_n$, you take their sum using regular addition then subtract $n$ if the result is greater than or equal to $n$.

In $Z_{2 \times 3 \times 5}$, in otherwords $Z_{30}$, you have 3 pairs of number 2 apart that are coprime to 30. Now, let's see what happens when we take all the pairs of numbers 2 apart that are coprime to 210 in $Z_{210}$. Take all the pairs that are 1 more and 1 less than a multiple of 30. Exactly one of those pairs has a multiple of 7 in the higher number and exactly one of them has a multiple of 7 in the lower number. Furthermore, the one with a multiple of 7 in the higher number is necessarily distinct from the one with a multiple of 7 in the lower number. A similar thing is true for all pairs that are 11 more and 13 more than a multiple of 30. The same goes for all pairs that are 17 more and 19 more than a multiple of 30. This proves that exactly $3 \times 5$ such pairs exist in $Z_{210}$. Similarly, it can be proven that exactly $3 \times 5 \times 9$ such pairs exist in $Z_{2,310}$ and so on. The problem is 169 is less than 2,310 so pairs of number 2 apart that are coprime to 2,310 and less than 2,310 are not necessarily twin primes. Maybe some day, we will be able to find a proof of certain random properties of the distribution of such pairs in $Z_n$ where $n$ is the product of all prime numbers less than a very large prime number $p$ and prove from the random properties that some of those pairs are less than $p^2$ and are therefore twin primes.